# Build the ssis and ssrs packages using Gradle

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, gradle, reporting-services, ssis

I want to build SSIS project .dtsx files
Even I want to build SSRS project .rdl files

I don't want to take IDE support.

Because i want to Continuous Integration using Jenkins so it required to write build script for all the ssis and ssrs.

I selected gradle as build tool.

The Build process should be like

Clean (delete some directory)

Build (compile the source code of ssis and ssrs project)

Package (wrap all compiled code in specific archive)

I want to do it by Gradle or Command line 
But i didn't find any article to do this by manual or some script.
Please help me .
Thanks

Comment: `msbuild` or `devenv /build` is probably what you're looking for. Try googling for msbuild ssis or msbuild ssrs -  there are tons of (long) references

Comment: What have you tried? Please show that you have tried to solve the problem on your own. Stackoverflow is not a service where people write code for you.

Comment: I am not asking to write code but i googled it but i didn't find any solution to do that.
That's why i am asking question.
Thanks for reply and please mark my reputation positive .

Comment: With all due respect, the way your question is currently written, it is difficult for someone to help you solve your problem and thereby learn Gradle, unless they have happened to solve the exact same problem. It is perhaps, shall we say, less likely. If you make an attempt to write the Gradle code which you think solve the problem, and then post a question asking for example why it doesn't work (you might even find that it does!), then the other users here will have a much easier time helping you to help yourself.

Comment: More concretely (and perhaps more usefully), if you read some of the documentation of Gradle, you will learn how to write a Gradle Task to perform a custom thing you need done. Perhaps try doing that, and come back with more specific questions when you get stuck.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to build ssis project using devenv.com

The folder Structure like

```
D:\BuildDemo
    |------DataCollector
        |------DataCollector
                    |------bin
                            |------Development
                                        |------*.dtsx           //source code
                                        |------DataCollector.ispac
                    |------obj
                    |------*.*
        |------DataCollector.sln
```

The command to build the ssis project is
We need to pass solution file as parameter to devenv.com to execute packages.

```
D:\BuildDemo\DataCollector>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" DataCollector.sln /build "Development|Default"
```